# My loop isn't working well in this little game I just create

Tags: c, loops

I'm recently introducing myself to C programming. I've tried in the past with web developing, like html or css, but not really deeper. Well, I'm learning from a book about C programming. I see a dice game, and tried to emulate it just for fun and learning how it works, but didn't work well(My intention was that if lifeGohan or lifeJoel gets to '0' it stops. Just like one die, and 'the battle' stops.). I'm not following any guide for this specific game I just created. So, I'm just trying many things without good results.
Can you give me some pieces of advice, please?

This is my code in Tried N°1

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctype.h>

main()
{
    int attackJoel, attackGohan, lifeJoel, lifeGohan, KO;
    time_t t;
    
    srand(time(&t));
    
    lifeGohan=20;
    lifeJoel=20;
    
    printf("Actual Life Joel: %d\tActual Life Gohan: %d\n", lifeJoel, lifeGohan);
    
    do
    {
        attackJoel=(rand() % 6)+1;
        attackGohan=(rand() % 6)+1;
        
        lifeJoel=lifeJoel-attackGohan;
        lifeGohan=lifeGohan-attackJoel;
        
        printf("\nActual Life Joel: %d\tActual Life Gohan: %d\n", lifeJoel, lifeGohan);
    }
    while((lifeJoel>0) || (lifeGohan>0));
}
```

Tried N°2

```
main()
{
    int attackJoel, attackGohan, lifeJoel, lifeGohan, KO;
    time_t t;
    
    srand(time(&t));
    
    lifeGohan=20;
    lifeJoel=20;
    
    printf("Actual Life Joel: %d\tActual Life Gohan: %d\n", lifeJoel, lifeGohan);
    
    do
    {
        attackJoel=(rand() % 6)+1;
        attackGohan=(rand() % 6)+1;
        
        lifeJoel=lifeJoel-attackGohan;
        lifeGohan=lifeGohan-attackJoel;
        
        printf("\nActual Life Joel: %d\tActual Life Gohan: %d\n", lifeJoel, lifeGohan);

        if((lifeJoel<=0) || (lifeGohan<=0))
        {
            KO=0;
        }
    }
    while(KO==0);
}
```

Comment: `while((lifeJoel>0) || (lifeGohan>0));` ==> `while((lifeJoel>0) && (lifeGohan>0));` , and fyi, be more descriptive than "but didn't work well." . That's nowhere *near* informative enough.

Comment: Your book is probably out of date. `main()` should be spelled `int main()` since around 1999. Your compiler, if it doesn't warn you about it, is out of date too.

Comment: Sorry for the missunderstanding with little information. My intention was that if lifeGohan or lifeJoel gets to '0' it stops. Just like one die, and 'the battle' stops.

Comment: If I just go with `&&` it means that both most reach 0, but my intention is that if anyone 'dies'(got 0 at least one of them), it stops.

Comment: I didn't know about it `int main`, I was following a book named "C Progamming ABSOLUTE BEGINNER'S GUIDE third edition". I though it was the right thing to do. I'm using VS Code.

Comment: _If I just go with && it means that both most reach 0_ - no, you miss that this is not the condition for stopping, but for continuing, and for that both must be above 0.

Comment: I recommend you safely dispose of it and find another book.

Answer (score 0):

How does the loop stop?  Did you initialise the variable? Does it ever change?

Make K0 non-zero to stop the loop.

Comment: Not remarking on style, nor naming of this variable.

Comment: Better to make K0 a boolean, but as pointed out above the poster seems to be using an old C book that might be from before booleans. But even so, setting `K0=(lifeJoel<=0) || (lifeGohan<=0)` would ensure K0 is updated in both cases.

Comment: I'm trying to stop the loop just when one(or both) gets 0. But as how I tried, it failed, it keeps going after 0, and don't get why.

Comment: @JohnBayko it works! nice! I wouldn't get this solution for myself. I mean, two comparative `<=` inside an int is something I didn't tried before. Thanks!

Comment: @Joel You would have gotten it sooner or later, this is very good for what it is. Modern IDE's stifle some skills because they tell you things we should be teaching. I gather you could not debug (DDD, cgdb or MVC?).